# Do I need to the field I am creating in the case statement in select statement?

Tags: sql, subquery, case-statement

Figured it out! I had quotes around the 'FulFillment Method' after the 'end as' part of the case expression. Once I removed the quotes it ran!

I am getting this error when I run the below code:

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
> mismatched input ''FulFillmentMethod'' expecting {, ';'}(line 45, pos 14)

This error started to occur after adding the case statement to the query. Prior to adding the case statement, everything ran perfectly fine.

Do I need to add FulFillment method to the select statement?

```
create or replace view bu_XXXX.X_Seasonal as
        SELECT
          daily.StoreNumber,
          daily.ChannelNetOriginated,
          FlexFulFillmentSubtype,
          SalesDollar,
          SalesUnit,
          ClearSalesDollar,
          ClearSalesUnit,
          PromoSalesDollar,
          PromoSalesUnit,
          RegularSalesDollar,
          RegularSalesUnit,
          Date,
          DateYear,
          DateYearMonth,
          Week,
          item.ItemNumber,
          item.Department,
          item.Class,
          item.Subclass,
          item.HSY_Brand,
          item.HSY_Manufacturer,
          item.Style,
          item.ItemDescription,
          item.X_DPCI_and_Description AS Item,
          item.X_DPCI,
          item.DPCI,
          item.HSY_Subsegment,
          Store.Region,
          Store.Zipcode,
          Store.State_Name as State,
          Store.Store_ABBR as StoreFormat,
          Store.CMSC_F,
          Store.LocationType,
  CASE
      WHEN( daily.ChannelNetOriginated = 'DC') THEN Store.LocationType
      WHEN( daily.StoreNumber in ('3134','3991')) THEN 'DIRECT VENDOR SHIP'
      WHEN (Store.CMSC_F = 'FC STORE' )THEN 'FULFILLMENT CENTER'
      WHEN ((daily.ChannelNetOriginated = 'ONLINE' AND FlexFulFillmentSubtype in ('SHIP FROM STORE', 'SHIP TO STORE', 'SHIPT', 'STORE PICK-UP'))) THEN 'FLEXIBLE FULFILLMENT'
      WHEN ((daily.ChannelNetOriginated = 'STORE' AND Store.CMSC_F in ('SUPER TARGET', 'P FRESH', 'EXPRESS TARGET', 'CITY TARGET', 'GENERAL MERCHANDISING'))) THEN 'STORE'
      ELSE 'NA'
      END  as FulFillmentMethod
        FROM 
          std_X.dailydata daily
        LEFT JOIN std_X.items item
        ON daily.ItemNumber = item.ItemNumber
        AND daily.VendorNumber = item.VendorNumber
       INNER JOIN std_X.stores Store
        ON daily.StoreNumber = Store.StoreNumber
        and DateYear <> '2018'
```

Comment: SQL knows no `CASE` *statements*, so you cannot add them to any query. What you have is a `CASE` **expression**.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't conditions be like this?

```
  WHEN 
      (
             (daily.ChannelNetOriginated = 'ONLINE' 
                 AND FlexFulFillmentSubtype in ('SHIP FROM STORE', 'SHIP TO STORE', 'SHIPT', 'STORE PICK-UP')
             ) 
      )
      THEN 'FLEXIBLE FULFILLMENT'
  WHEN (
             (daily.ChannelNetOriginated = 'STORE' 
                 AND Store.CMSC_F in ('SUPER', 'EXPRESS', 'CITY', 'GENERAL MERCHANDISING')
             ) 
       )
       THEN 'STORE'
```

Comment: Or just remove the superfluous parenthesis all together...

Comment: that fixed the error I was getting! Now I am experiencing a different error at the end of my case statement.